# Multiplayer rigidbody movement not synced (Photon)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, multiplayer, photon, rigid-bodies

I am creating a multiplayer games with spaceships that you can enter. I am using photon for multiplayer.

As you can see on image below I have in PhotonView ship's Rigidbody, Transform and same on Player.
[image: my PhotonView Settings]

But when I enter ship the view from other player looks extremly laggy (if I push the ship it syncs normally). Here's a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P1bJvEM9SIU&feature=youtu.be) showing the problem.

My player is connected to the ship using fixed joint.
Here is my shortened code:

```
void Update()
{
    //Raycast to check for ship
    if ((Physics.Raycast(look, out hit, 9f) && hit.collider.tag == "Ship")
    {
        //set variables
        shipObj = hit.collider.gameObject.transform.parent.gameObject;
        ship = shipObj.GetComponent<SmallShipController>();

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.R))
        {
            //check if ship is driven
            if (!ship.driven)
            {
                driving = true;
                ship.ChangeDriven();
                transform.position = ship.driverSeat.transform.position;
                transform.rotation = ship.driverSeat.transform.rotation;
                playersCamera.transform.position = ship.thirdPersonPosition.position;
                playersCamera.transform.rotation = ship.thirdPersonPosition.rotation;
                rb.detectCollisions = false;
                rb.mass = 0;
                rb.drag = 0;
                rb.angularDrag = 0;
                photonView.RPC("SetJoint", PhotonTargets.AllBuffered, shipObj.GetPhotonView().viewID);
            }
        }
        if (driving)
        {
            if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A))
            {
                ship.rb.AddRelativeForce(Vector3.left * ship.moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
            }
            if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W))
            {
                ship.rb.AddRelativeForce(Vector3.forward * ship.moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
            }
            if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D))
            {
                ship.rb.AddRelativeForce(Vector3.right * ship.moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
            }
            if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S))
            {
                ship.rb.AddRelativeForce(Vector3.back * ship.moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
            }
            if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space))
            {
                ship.rb.AddRelativeForce(Vector3.up * ship.moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime * 0.5f);
            }
            if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift))
            {
                ship.rb.AddRelativeForce(Vector3.down * ship.moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime * 0.5f);
            }
            if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Q))
            {
                ship.rb.AddRelativeTorque(new Vector3(0, 0, Time.deltaTime * ship.moveSpeed));
            }
            if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.E))
            {
                ship.rb.AddRelativeTorque(new Vector3(0, 0, Time.deltaTime * -ship.moveSpeed));
            }
            if (Input.GetAxisRaw("Mouse Y") > 0.5f || Input.GetAxisRaw("Mouse Y") < 0.5f || Input.GetAxisRaw("Mouse X") > 0.5f || Input.GetAxisRaw("Mouse X") < 0.5f)
            {
                ship.rb.AddRelativeTorque(new Vector3(-Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y"), Input.GetAxis("Mouse X"), 0) * Time.deltaTime * ship.rotationSpeed);
            }
            if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.C))
            {
                ship.rb.velocity = ship.rb.velocity * 0.99f;
                ship.rb.angularVelocity = ship.rb.angularVelocity * 0.99f;
            }
        }
    }
}

[PunRPC]
void SetJoint(int shipView)
{
    shipObj = PhotonView.Find(shipView).gameObject;
    shipObj.GetComponent<FixedJoint>().connectedBody = rb;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would not recommend this technic at all, if your player joins a physics object, it should completely take over it. Make the ship a scene Object that can have its owner changed, and when a player wants to enter it make this player the owner of that ship. And then you can rely on onwership management and safely control the spacecraft from various players.

also, I suggest you use the Photon Forum, you'll have more chance to get replies.